# Can't make the image to appear in the section selected

Tags: graphics, floats

I am having problems getting the image to appear exactly below the text. I have defined it to be below the text and inside of the brackets but it doesn't seem to work. I have attached a picture of the output I get (I am using a downloaded template).
[image: error.]

```
\documentclass[a4 paper]{article}

\usepackage[inner=1.5cm,outer=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{{/Desktop/securityAnalytics/KevinBHMW01/}}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{amsgen,amsmath,amstext,amsbsy,amsopn,tikz,amssymb,tkz-linknodes}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue,  linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue]

{hyperref}

\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}

\newcommand{\homework}[6]{

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\thispagestyle{plain}

\newpage

\setcounter{page}{1}

\noindent

\begin{center}

\framebox{

\vbox{\vspace{2mm}

\hbox to 6.28in { {\bf EE5453: Security Analytics \hfill} }

\vspace{6mm}

\hbox to 6.28in { {\Large \hfill #1 (#2)  \hfill} }

\vspace{6mm}

\hbox to 6.28in { {\it Instructor: #3 \hfill Student: #5} }

\vspace{2mm}}}

\end{center}

\markboth{#5 -- #1}{#5 -- #1}

\vspace*{4mm}}

\begin{document}

\homework{Assignment \#1}{February 13 2019 }{Wonjun Lee, PhD}{}{Kevin 
Brinneman}{}

{\begin{tikzpicture}[outline/.style={draw=#1,thick,fill=#1!5}]

\node [outline=yellow] at (0,1) {\bf Dataset and tensors at pixel level:};

\end{tikzpicture}}

{MNIST data-set is widely used for classification and image recognition, this is considered a simple task and involves minimum programming skills but it is important because is often used as a benchmark to test how accurate our deep learning models are. The data set has been split in two sections: Training and testing. The  data consists of 60,000 images of handwritten digits from different subjects and the testing data set consists of 10,000 images for  our model.Per image in the data-set, has a size of 28x28; each element of the 28 by 28 matrix represents one pixel and each pixel consists of a 0-D tensor, it can range from 0 up to 255; where 0 is taken to be black color and 255 white, anything in between is gray scale.}

\begin{figure}

\centering

\includegraphics[scale=.5]{5}[thbp]

\caption{Handwritten number 5 from dataset.}

\label{fig1}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Thanks for posting a code! However, how many others do you think will be able to use `\graphicspath{{/Desktop/securityAnalytics/KevinBHMW01/}}`? And why does you code have so many empty lines, was there a problem when posting it here? (And when I fix the obvious issues, I am left with `! LaTeX Error: Environment dataset undefined.`. Where is that environment defined?)

Comment: it isn't clear what your problem is (and we can not run the example) but I note that you have surrounded the `\includegraphics` with `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` the only purpose of that environment is to specify that the content may be moved to avoid bad white space at page breaks. the default positioning is `[tbp]` so most likely it went to the top of the current page, perhaps you want `\begin{figure}[thbp]` so it will try to set it at that position.

Comment: Hey, I am sorry for all the blank spaces. I was trying to make the code readable, if I don't use the space it out, the code looks like a segment of text. Basically what I am trying to do is to get the image below the text. Not above the header. I have attached a picture and also my code. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I have deleted the dataset environment, it is not required anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shown code has some issues I corrected in the following MWE.

This are the most important issues:

1. To get DiN A4 paper you have to use class option `a4paper` (no blank between `a4` and `paper`).
2. Package `hyperref` should be called last in your case.
3. You need not to write `{...}` around your environment `tikzpicture`.
4. Same for the text `MNIST ... scale.`
5. `[thbp]` is an option for environment `figure` and **not** `\includegraphics`
6. Because I do not have your image `5` I used `example-image` from package MWE.

The main error resulting in a wrong position for your image was the wrong place for option `[thbp]`.

With the following code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[inner=1.5cm,outer=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsgen,amsmath,amstext,amsbsy,amsopn,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-linknodes}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[%
  colorlinks=true, 
  urlcolor=blue,  
  linkcolor=blue, 
  citecolor=blue
]{hyperref} % <=========================================================

\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}

\newcommand{\homework}[6]{%
  \pagestyle{myheadings}
  \thispagestyle{plain}
  \newpage
  \setcounter{page}{1}
  \noindent
  \begin{center}
    \framebox{%
      \vbox{\vspace{2mm}
      \hbox to 6.28in { {\bf EE5453: Security Analytics \hfill} }
      \vspace{6mm}
      \hbox to 6.28in { {\Large \hfill #1 (#2)  \hfill} }
      \vspace{6mm}
      \hbox to 6.28in { {\it Instructor: #3 \hfill Student: #5} }
      \vspace{2mm}}%
    }
  \end{center}
  \markboth{#5 -- #1}{#5 -- #1}
  \vspace*{4mm}%
}


\begin{document}

\homework
  {Assignment \#1}%    1
  {February 13 2019 }% 2
  {Wonjun Lee, PhD}%   3
  {}%                  4
  {Kevin Brinneman}%   5
  {}%                  6

\begin{tikzpicture}[outline/.style={draw=#1,thick,fill=#1!5}]
  \node [outline=yellow] at (0,1) {\bf Dataset and tensors at pixel level:};
\end{tikzpicture}

MNIST data-set is widely used for classification and image recognition, 
this is considered a simple task and involves minimum programming skills 
but it is important because is often used as a benchmark to test how 
accurate our deep learning models are. The data set has been split in 
two sections: Training and testing. The  data consists of 60,000 images 
of handwritten digits from different subjects and the testing data set 
consists of 10,000 images for  our model. Per image in the data-set, has 
a size of 28x28; each element of the 28 by 28 matrix represents one pixel 
and each pixel consists of a 0-D tensor, it can range from 0 up to 255; 
where 0 is taken to be black color and 255 white, anything in between 
is gray scale.

\begin{figure}[thbp] % <================================================
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image}
  \caption{Handwritten number 5 from dataset.}
  \label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I get the result:

[image: resulting pdf]